# How to interpret MediaCodec error messages?

Tags: android-mediacodec

I am trying to decode audio data encoded in opus using the MediaCodec class in Android. I am getting an exception which I believe has something to do with how the decoder is configured, but I do not know.

Is there any guide, documentation or anything at all on how to interpret error messages from MediaCodec (or the underlying codecs it uses)?

The following is the error message I get:

```
E/ACodec: [OMX.google.opus.decoder] ERROR(0x80001001)
    signalError(omxError 0x80001001, internalError -2147483648)
E/MediaCodec: Codec reported err 0x80001001, actionCode 0, while in state 6
```

Answer (score 0):

Was struggling with a similar problem related to video encoding and the same, as far as I can tell, undocumented Error 0x80001001.
My Issue was that my specified [MediaFormat](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaFormat) was missing a non optional configuration key.
There is different requirements for encoders/decoders so check the description on the right.